# How do I require one of two jsonschema properties, but also set a default?

Tags: python, jsonschema, default-value, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I try to validate a jsonschema that defines a circle either with a `radius` or a `diameter` or neither and then just sets a default radius. This is my schema:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "position": {},
    "radius": {
      { "type": "number" }
    },
    "diameter": {
      { "type": "number" }
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": ["radius"]
    },
    {
      "required": ["diameter"]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "radius": {
          "default": 16
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

This is the validator, that sets the default value (as described at [JSON schema FAQ](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq)):

```py
from jsonschema import Draft7Validator, validators

def extend_with_default(validator_class):
  validate_properties = validator_class.VALIDATORS['properties']

  def set_defaults(validator, properties, instance, schema):
    for property, subschema in properties.items():
      if 'default' in subschema:
        instance.setdefault(property, subschema['default'])

    for error in validate_properties(
      validator, properties, instance, schema,
    ):
      yield error

  return validators.extend(
    validator_class, {'properties' : set_defaults},
  )
Validator = extend_with_default(Draft7Validator)
```

This validator sets the default value before I validate the schema, so I can only set the radius or neither, but setting the diameter will always raise an error.
If I change this to validate first and set default values later (which I would rather not, but ok), then it sets the default radius despite the required diameter already existing.

Is there some way to implement this without hard-coding it by setting the default-radius in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validator does not need to be changed. This is a possible soluation:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "position": {},
    "radius": {
      { "type": "number" }
    },
    "diameter": {
      { "type": "number" }
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "not": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "required": ["radius"]
        },
        {
          "required": ["diameter"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "radius": {
        "default": 16
      }
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": ["radius"]
    },
    {
      "required": ["diameter"]
    }
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

`if` will be only true, if neither radius or diameter are set. Only then will the default radius be set. Afterwards `oneOf` checks, if only one of the parameters is set at the same time.

Comment: The `oneOf` subschema is mutually exclusive with the `if` condition - it is impossible for one of radius and diameter to be present, while also neither of them being present.

Comment: That's exactly the trick! The if condition is only used to set the default values (if they don't already exist). After that, the validation can no longer reach the ```then``` part and only evaluate the ```oneOf``` subschema.

Comment: That's not how JSON Schema works. *All* the keywords are evaluated -- the oneOf subschemas will always be used. Perhaps you meant to put the oneOf inside an 'else' clause?

Comment: The evaluation happens in two steps here: `instance.setdefault()` will set every default value that it can reach. It does _not_ need to satisfy the schema to set the values, so `oneOf` is irrelevant here.

`validate_properties()` will then always satisfy the schema. The if condition is (as you pointed out) also evaluated and equates to false, so `then` is never reached during validation.

I tested it with all possible configurations of setting/omitting radius and diameter.

Comment: ok, that is very weird and contrary to the JSON Schema spec, but you've got to work with what the library gives you...

Comment: As you suggested, moving `oneOf` in an 'else' clause should also work and might be easier to read.